# log4j2 does not print messages fired in a thread

Tags: java, log4j2

I am surprised that log4j2 does not print messages when it is executed in a thread.

**Details**

- log4j2 version 2.6.2
- **Debug and runtime affected**
- two standard appenders (file, console)
- calls like `LOG.error("msg");`, `LOG.error("msg", e);` or `LOG.info("bad news", e);`
- runs in a **separate thread** and all subsequent LOG calls are not represented
- Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0)
- Java JDK 1.8.0_51
- Maven 3.x project but launched out of Eclipse
- Win 7 (Professional)

**Init**

`private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(MainProcess.class);`

**Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" packages="xyz.my.appenders">
<Appenders>
    <File name="file" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <LimitAppender name="log-viewer" numberOfLines="30">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </LimitAppender>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="xyz.my.application" level="DEBUG"/>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        <!-- <AppenderRef ref="log-viewer"/> -->
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Trace of log4j2** (200 of 283 lines)

```
2016-07-20 09:42:14,396 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2016-07-20 09:42:14,409 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2016-07-20 09:42:15,040 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_51, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2016-07-20 09:42:15,115 main DEBUG Took 0.074225 seconds to load 1 plugins from package xyz.my.appenders
2016-07-20 09:42:15,115 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 100 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,116 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,119 main DEBUG No scheduled items
2016-07-20 09:42:15,119 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,121 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,132 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,132 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,144 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-07-20 09:42:15,145 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,179 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,185 main DEBUG createAppender(fileName="logfile.log", append="true", locking="null", name="file", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n), Filter=null, advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
2016-07-20 09:42:15,189 main DEBUG Starting FileManager logfile.log
2016-07-20 09:42:15,189 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,190 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-07-20 09:42:15,190 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,192 main DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,193 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:15,194 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-07-20 09:42:15,194 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-2
2016-07-20 09:42:15,202 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="console", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-07-20 09:42:15,203 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-07-20 09:42:15,204 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
2016-07-20 09:42:15,204 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,204 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-07-20 09:42:15,205 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=xyz.my.appenders.LimitMemoryAppender].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,205 main DEBUG createAppender(name="log-viewer", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%p] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n), numberOfLines="30")
2016-07-20 09:42:15,206 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,207 main DEBUG createAppenders(={file, console, log-viewer})
2016-07-20 09:42:15,207 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,210 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="DEBUG", name="xyz.my.project", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-07-20 09:42:15,213 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,214 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-07-20 09:42:15,214 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,214 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="file", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-07-20 09:42:15,214 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,215 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="log-viewer", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-07-20 09:42:15,215 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,216 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={console, file, log-viewer}, ={}, Configuration(C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-07-20 09:42:15,217 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2016-07-20 09:42:15,217 main DEBUG createLoggers(={xyz.my.project, root})
2016-07-20 09:42:15,219 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml] initialized
2016-07-20 09:42:15,219 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2016-07-20 09:42:15,219 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,220 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@26a1ab54...
2016-07-20 09:42:15,220 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,221 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,221 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,222 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,222 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-1
2016-07-20 09:42:15,222 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,222 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,222 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@26a1ab54 OK
2016-07-20 09:42:15,295 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@74e52ef6
2016-07-20 09:42:15,295 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): 'c387f44' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ed3ccb2
2016-07-20 09:42:15,297 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,297 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=StatusLogger'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,298 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=ContextSelector'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,298 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=*'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,298 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=*'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,299 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,299 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,299 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2016-07-20 09:42:15,301 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44
2016-07-20 09:42:15,303 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=StatusLogger
2016-07-20 09:42:15,305 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=ContextSelector
2016-07-20 09:42:15,307 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=
2016-07-20 09:42:15,308 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=xyz.my.myproject
2016-07-20 09:42:15,309 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=console
2016-07-20 09:42:15,310 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=file
2016-07-20 09:42:15,310 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=log-viewer
2016-07-20 09:42:15,312 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,312 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,312 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=c387f44] at URI C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ed3ccb2) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-07-20 09:42:15,313 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2016-07-20 09:42:15,314 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=c387f44, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ed3ccb2] started OK.
2016-07-20 09:42:15.501 [main] [DEBUG] main.SQLHelperMain (SQLHelperMain.java:95) - Adding icon
2016-07-20 09:42:16.168 [Thread-2] [INFO] main.SQLHelperMain (SQLHelperMain.java:390) - SQLHelperMain.parsingFinished(true)
2016-07-20 09:42:16.424 [main] [DEBUG] main.SQLHelperMain (SQLHelperMain.java:82) - Open SQLHelperUI
2016-07-20 09:42:17,652 main DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=c387f44, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ed3ccb2]...
2016-07-20 09:42:17,653 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44]
2016-07-20 09:42:17,654 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=StatusLogger]
2016-07-20 09:42:17,654 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=ContextSelector]
2016-07-20 09:42:17,654 main TRACE Unregistering 2 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=xyz.my.project, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=]
2016-07-20 09:42:17,655 main TRACE Unregistering 3 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=console, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=file, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Appenders,name=log-viewer]
2016-07-20 09:42:17,655 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2016-07-20 09:42:17,656 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2016-07-20 09:42:17,657 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c387f44,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2016-07-20 09:42:17,657 main TRACE Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml]...
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main TRACE XmlConfiguration notified 3 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping 2 LoggerConfigs.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main TRACE XmlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main TRACE XmlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,658 main DEBUG Shutting down FileManager logfile.log
2016-07-20 09:42:17,659 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
2016-07-20 09:42:17,659 main TRACE XmlConfiguration stopped 3 remaining Appenders.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,659 main TRACE XmlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 3 LoggerConfigs.
2016-07-20 09:42:17,659 main DEBUG Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=C:\...\TheProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK
2016-07-20 09:42:17,660 main DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=c387f44, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ed3ccb2]...
2016-07-20 09:42:27,713 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,713 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2016-07-20 09:42:27,715 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-07-20 09:42:27,715 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-3
2016-07-20 09:42:27,716 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Starting LoggerContext[name=c387f44, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@35644357]...
2016-07-20 09:42:27,716 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context[name=c387f44] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@35644357) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-07-20 09:42:27,716 AWT-EventQueue-0 DEBUG Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@4d399216
2016-07-20 09:42:27,716 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,717 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,717 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,718 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,718 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,719 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,720 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,721 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,721 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,722 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,722 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,723 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,723 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,724 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,724 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,724 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,725 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,725 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,726 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,726 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,727 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,727 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,728 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,728 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-testc387f44.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,728 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,729 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,729 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,730 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,730 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,731 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,731 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,732 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,732 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,732 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,733 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,733 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,734 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,734 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,735 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,735 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,735 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,736 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,736 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,737 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,737 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,737 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,738 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,738 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,738 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,739 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,739 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,740 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,740 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,740 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,741 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,741 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,742 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,742 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,742 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,743 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,743 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,744 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,744 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,744 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,745 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,745 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,746 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,746 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,746 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,747 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,747 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,747 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2c387f44.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,748 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,748 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,748 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,749 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,749 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,750 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,750 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,750 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,751 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,751 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,751 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,752 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,752 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,753 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,753 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,753 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
2016-07-20 09:42:27,754 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44.
2016-07-20 09:42:27,754 AWT-EventQueue-0 TRACE Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 class loader.
```

Please let me know if you wish further details.

Comment: Your log4j configuration may help :)

Comment: @Berger: It's a plain simple config. Despite, I will add it.

Comment: Could you post one sample thread, along with how `LOG` is created ?

Comment: @Berger: The thread is created via an instance implementing `Runnable` and started with the method `start()`.

Comment: Can you show the output you get when you switch on log4j2 internal status logging by setting `<Configuration status="trace"` in the beginning of the configuration file?

Comment: @RemkoPopma: I've added the first 200 lines of the trace. SO does not allow a post with more than 30k chars.

Comment: It seems that 1st initialization works fine, then 10 seconds later it initializes again for some reason. I can't see the last lines so not sure if the 2nd initialization succeeds or fails.

Comment: It should work correctly: It always prints `DEBUG LoggerContext[name=...] started OK.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me:

Initially, I wrote a Swing application opening the UI via `appl.setVisible(true);` in the **Main thread**. At the end I also added `LogManager.shutdown();` to clean up the resources once terminated.

While browsing the internet and getting more info on Swing via SO, the code emerged to a proper multithreaded application (see `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});`) while keeping the shutdown hook of the `LogManager`.

**Fix**

Due to the outstanding good answer of @rgoers I saw that the name of the logger changed from *xyz.my.logger:**DEBUG*** to *xyz.my.logger:**OFF***!

Comment: Bear in mind that Log4j 2 will do any necessary cleanup automatically in a JVM shutdown hook so there is no need to explicitly call `LogManager.shutdown()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sure like to see your application. From the log it looks like the application has ended. AWT-EventQueue-0 (a new Thread?) then starts running. Logging has shutdown so it tries to reinitialize but has no idea what configuration to use. To solve this the threads your application creates need to run before the main thread ends.

Comment: This sounds like a very promising input. What comes to my mind is: How can I write a Swing application if I use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});`. Moreover, in line 200+ it prints once more the correct location of the config file.